# Interpretation of coxph and cox.zph function result

Tags: survival, cox-model

My output from coxph() and cox.zph() function as follows

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(survival.d) ~ stage, data = pancreatic, 
    ties = "breslow")

         coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z    p
stageM 0.2567    1.2927   0.3988 0.644 0.52

Likelihood ratio test=0.44  on 1 df, p=0.5095
n= 41, number of events= 41 
> resid    chisq df    p
stage      1  1 0.32
GLOBAL     1  1 0.32
```

Sorry for the unorganized output, I am new here so I also want to know how to paste my output properly
Anyways, global p value from coxph()function is 0.5095
and p value from cox.zph() is 0.32.

So how should I interpret this output?
cox.zph() is to check the assumption of proportional hazards model. So based on this I could say assumption holds.
However, coxph() is not significant; stage covariates do not make a significant difference on survival rate.

Thank you in advance

Comment: @Stochastic thank you for changing my question

Answer (score 2):

You are implying that decisions are simple binary ones that can be based on "statistical significance".  This should not be the case.  To some extent you can separate the "association with outcome" assessment from the "is the hazard ratio constant" question.  On the latter you can say that with your current sample size of 41 patients, all of whom died (and we assume no patients who started the study were censored) there is insufficient evidence to reject the supposition that the effect of stage is constant over time on the hazard scale.  Likewise for the effect of stage on survival time.  But do note that if a predictor is very weak, non-proportional hazards is not necessarily an issue at all.  When a predictor has zero effect, it **must** be in proportional hazards.